# Voting on unfamiliar topics

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19/should-we-be-a-high-voting-site?rq=1) seems strongly related.

Is there site policy or lacking that some convention on what level of knowledge you should have / what level of effort you should put in before voting on a question? For example I regularly vote on econometric topics were I find the question to be precise, but because I am not very familiar with that area I may upvote questions with well-known answers.

And what level of effort do you put in if a longish or technical answer seems correct? Do you take time to understand its entirety? (I don't always do this.)

Skimming things may cause serious problems. Currently there is a well received question (I will not link to it) that I don't think is a good one with a well received answer that is mathematically incorrect.

EDIT: The question has since been deleted by the owner. At the time of deletion it had about six upvotes and the incorrect answer had about two.

Comment: This is besides the point you are raising, but I take it that since you do not link to the thread where you have spotted a mathematically incorrect answer, it means that you have already raised the issue there? Because provably incorrect answers are the worst nightmare for a Q&A site that wants to be taken seriously.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I have raised the issue there before posting here but you are right to make a point of it.

Comment: I would like policy on this too, I am often on up-voting; but if it is something like Micro I know nothing about I am often unsure whether to vote and often don't for these - but quite liberally do in fields I kind-of know like Macro .. also which I am not sure is okay.

Comment: Related discussion on the overarching network meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226515/is-my-cursory-upvoting-system-faulty